# Transactional integrity Sharepoint List

Tags: database, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, transactions

Is it possibly to guarantee transactional integrity when storing information in a Sharepoint list (SP 2010)?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by `transactional integrity` in that context? Also, SharePoint 2008 does not exist, are you referring to 2007 or 2010?

Comment: I meant 2010. Thanks for pointing that out. What I need to know is whether an insert will completely succeed or fail or if you could have partial insert in some cases? Is it also possible to have a transaction scope covering two lists for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underneath the covers a single SharePoint operation like adding a list item can involve multiple database operations and they will all be protected by a single database transaction.  With that said, the product doesn't expose that transactional capability to you so that you can perform multiple SharePoint operations under the aegis of a single transaction.  To be very safe, you'll need to implement very carefully coded error handlers.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted. Who designs a *collaboration* server and thinks transaction support isn't necessary? What would happen if I just created an ambient transaction and did multiple SP operations? I bet SP uses ADO.NET, which is System.Transactions-aware, which ought to mean that as long as the SharePoint code is running in the same process, it might well join my transaction even if it doesn't know that it did. Admittedly this would at best be a dirty hack, but I'm not sure living without transactions is any better.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8f019e3b-0337-4aea-841c-d4104aff941b), SharePoint 2010 does not offer any transactional support out of the box.

The underlying database does support transactions, so a single insert will probably either succeed or fail, but if an error occurs during a complex routine involving multiple database operations, the data will end up being partially modified.

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint does not offer transaction support out of the box.

Here is a good resource on [Building a System.Transactions resource manager for SharePoint](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305175210/http://www.loisandclark.eu/pages/transactions.aspx)

Though I would save the effort and store any critical data directly into a RDB